# Get selected block every time a new block is selected in Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

I want to get the selected block (an inner block) every time a new block is selected.

I am trying the following:

```
edit() {
  const selectedBlock = wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' ).getSelectedBlock();
  
  useEffect( () => {
    console.log( selectedBlock );
  }, [ selectedBlock ] );
})
```

The selected block is returned only when the block renders. Nothing happens when I select a new inner block. It works only when I click out of the parent block, then click again an inner block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access site and block editor state data and use \`useSelect()\` or \`withSelect()\` to bind it to my components?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/390985/how-do-i-access-site-and-block-editor-state-data-and-use-useselect-or-withs)

Answer (score 0):

In short, use the `useSelect()` hook or the `withSelect()` HOC utility from [`@wordpress/data`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/) to create a subscription to selected value. Either will trigger a render whenever the selected value changes in state:

```js
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

edit() {
  const selectedBlock = useSelect(
    ( select ) => select( 'core/block-editor' ).getSelectedBlock()
  );

  useEffect( () => {
    console.log( selectedBlock );
  }, [ selectedBlock ] );
}
```