# Have parent block's isSelected be true if an innerblock is selected?

Tags: block-editor

I'm using `isSelected` to determine if a block is selected, but I'd also like to know if any innerblocks are selected.

I'm using `export default function Edit({ isSelected }) {}`

I believe this is done with `useSelect` but I'm not sure how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to know whether or not an inner-block is selected, you can leverage the `core/block-editor` store's [`hasSelectedInnerBlock()` selector](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-block-editor/#hasselectedinnerblock). For example, if using a `useSelect()` hook in a functional component, that might look as such:

```js
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

export default function Edit( { isSelected, clientId } ) {
  const is_inner_block_selected = useSelect(
    ( select ) => select( 'core/block-editor' ).hasSelectedInnerBlock( clientId )
  );

  // ...
}
```

After which you might use a simple `isSelected || is_inner_block_selected` condition to execute your specific functionality - or some other hook with with a `[ isSelected, is_inner_block_selected ]` dependency.

Of particular note, you can set the second argument of `hasSelectedInnerBlock()` to `true` for a deep check - that is, if you wish to know if *any descendant* is selected (in cases where you would like to know if the inner blocks themselves may have inner blocks which are selected):

```js
select( 'core/block-editor' ).hasSelectedInnerBlock( clientId, true )
```

Comment: For more information on what `useSelect()`/`withSelect()` does, I've written an introduction to the functions over [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/390985), which may (hopefully!) be of some use. In short, they create a subscription between a component and the state selectors which a component depends on such that when the value a selector retrieves changes, the component will re-render. In this case that means if `hasSelectedInnerBlock( clientId )` changes from returning `true` -> `false` or vis versa, the component will re-render with the new value.

Comment: Worked perfectly! I'd like to know more about the deep check though. I get what you mean by checking if inner, inner blocks are selected, but not how. Do you mean you'd add === true? Not sure how to code what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: It would just be `.hasSelectedInnerBlock( clientId, true )` :)

Answer (score 1):

I think @Elizabeth was trying to determine if a child block is selected *and also* if the block itself is selected. If so, building off of @bosco's example, you can create a utility function, like:

```
// in a file named useIsSelectedOrChild.js:

/**
 * Self or Child Selected
 *
 * This is essentially isSelected, extended to include if a child
 * block is selected.
 */
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

const useIsSelectedOrChild = (clientId, isSelected = null) => {
    let isSelectedOrChild = useSelect((select) =>
        select('core/block-editor').hasSelectedInnerBlock(clientId)
    );
    if (!isSelectedOrChild && isSelected !== null) {
        isSelectedOrChild = isSelected;
    }
    return isSelectedOrChild;
};

export default useIsSelectedOrChild;
```

Then you can simply import it into any blocks you want and reuse it:

```
import useIsSelectedOrChild from 'useIsSelectedOrChild';

export default function edit( { clientId, isSelected } ) {
  const isSelectedOrChild = useIsSelectedOrChild(clientId, isSelected);
  return (
    <div>Myself or a child is {isSelectedOrChild ? 'selected' : 'deselected'}</div>
  )
}
```